# How to split comma separated values from a column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column from a SQL Table with the values (they're from a movie database):

```
type

drama
comedy, romance
comedy
thriller, short
drama, romance
```

I want to separate and count them, with an output like:

```
type  count

drama 2
comedy 2
thriller 1
short 1
romance 2
```

how would you do this in the most simple-fastest way possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Bárbara! What have you tried so far?

Comment: In the simplest possible way? I would have normalized the database and not put multple values into a single attribute. Anything else will be messy. Not least because CSV is a family of formats).

Comment: sql isn't made for this, so you have to use a stored procedure for this

Comment: how many types will a movie have at most?  what database version are you using?

Comment: You *can* use a stored procedure for this, but you don't *have to*

Comment: For related issues, see my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would use a separate table movie_type with one row per type per movie.  Otherwise, you need to use substring_index to pick out each type and join to an ad hoc table (or a recursive cte) identifying which type to get from each row:

```
select type, count(*) from (
    select substring_index(substring_index(type, ', ', num),', ',-1) type
    from movie
    join (
        select 1 num union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
    ) nums on num <= (length(type)-length(replace(type,', ','')))/length(', ')+1
) movie_types
group by type;
```

`(length(foo)-length(replace(foo,'bar','')))/length('bar')` is the count of how many times 'bar' appears in foo.  You add one to the count of ', ' in type to get how many types are listed.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=aea165ea94d2f53f958bbe239a64d21e)